# SQL - Adding a cumulative count to each day of the week resetting every week

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a dataset that looks at the number of records people have overstayed at a hotel.
What I need to do is create a dataset that looks at how many days cumulatively are being overstayed in total over all the rooms.

I currently have a dimensions table that has details of the calendar. So I have the WeekStartDate, WeekEndDate, DayOfWeek etc...

Lets say I have this example dataset;

| UserID | PlannedStayDate | EndStayDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 858666 | 05/06/2023 | NULL |
| 334224 | 07/06/2023 | NULL |
| 484858 | 08/06/2023 | NULL |
| 324234 | 10/06/2023 | 11/06/2023 |
| 342455 | 11/06/2023 | NULL |
| 386849 | 11/06/2023 | NULL |

A NULL EndStayDate just means they are still in the room.

The Join I'm using for the Calendar Dimension view is

```
LEFT JOIN Calendar_tbl AS Cal ON C.Date = PlannedStayDate
```

If I write

```
SELECT DayOfWeek, COUNT(1) AS [TotalOverstayedDays] 
FROM X
LEFT JOIN Calendar_tbl AS CAL ON C.Date = X.PlannedStayDate
GROUP BY DayOfWeek
```

The Output of this table data is;

| DayOfWeek | TotalOverstayedDays |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | 1 |
| Tuesday | 0 |
| Wednesday | 1 |
| Thursday | 1 |
| Friday | 0 |
| Saturday | 1 |
| Sunday | 2 |

What I want to do is have a cumilative count on each day rolling that will reset weekly but I am not sure how to achieve this.

The output I would like to have is:

| DayOfWeek | TotalOverstayedDays |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | 1 |
| Tuesday | 1 |
| Wednesday | 2 |
| Thursday | 3 |
| Friday | 3 |
| Saturday | 4 |
| Sunday | 5 |

Where each day just adds to the previous day until the Sunday UNLESS the EndStayDate is entered and they have left, reducing the figure by the amount of people who have left, in this case, one on Sunday.

I have looked online and seen the use of functions via Window and RollUp but I don't know how to implement these into my query to use.

Comment: I would do [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/s_A4Kl4I), but _reset weekly_ is not clear. What is expected value for next Monday in your example? 0? 5? If end_date is null it means people leave on Sunday by default?

Comment: @PonderStibbons apologies, its for weekly reporting submissions so I would only need to capture data relating to a single week only each time. Even if the people are staying past the Sunday, it would revert back to 0 on the next Monday and do it again for the next week, they would simply be a count of 1 per overstay person on the next weeks dataset. Reset weekly isn't the best working, capturing data weekly is better used.

Answer (score 0):

This query captures data for specific week:

```
select dt, datename(weekday, dt) dn, count(userid) cnt
from calendar_tbl c
left join x on x.PlannedStayDate <= c.dt 
           and (c.dt < EndStayDate or EndStayDate is null)
where dt between '2023-06-05' and '2023-06-11' 
group by dt 
order by dt
```

This queries whole calendar, but for each week gets only rows where PlannedStayDate belongs to this week (is greater or equal then Monday):

```
select dt, datename(weekday, dt) dn, count(userid) cnt
from calendar_tbl c
left join x on x.PlannedStayDate <= c.dt 
           and x.PlannedStayDate 
              >= dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(day, -1, dt)), 0)  
           and (c.dt < EndStayDate or EndStayDate is null)
group by dt 
order by dt
```

[dbfiddle for both queries in SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/VhRzzz0w)

To find Mondays as first day of week I used solution from [this link](https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-datepart-sql-server/).